# Populate value from selected label react-select

Tags: reactjs, react-select

I am using react-select to select data from a JSON. I need to update the amount(value) field whenever the user selects a label.

```
  const aquaticCreatures = [
  { label: 'Shark', value: '500' },
  { label: 'Dolphin', value: '200' },
  { label: 'Whale', value: '600' },
  { label: 'Octopus', value: '800' },
  { label: 'Crab', value: '209' },
  { label: 'Lobster', value: 'test' },
];
```

State variables

```
  const [name, setName] = useState("");
  const [amount, setAmount] = useState("");
```

And the form that contains inputs name and amount

```
<div className="form-group">
          <label htmlFor="name">Product name</label>
          <Select
        id="name"
        options={aquaticCreatures}
        onChange={(e) => setName(e.label)}
        //value={name}
      />
        </div>
        <div className="form-group">
          <label htmlFor="AmountField">Amount</label>
          <input
            className="form-control"
            id="amount"
            value={amount}
            //onChange={(e) => setAmount(e.value)}
          />
        </div>
```

This might be a basic thing, Kindly help me! Thought about refs but not sure, since I am new to react.

Comment: I had to specify the setAmount within the same onChange Method so that the values get populated on both fields.                                                                                              
<Select
        id="name"
        options={aquaticCreatures}
        onChange={(e) => { setName(e.label); setAmount(e.value); }}
    >